# Set cookie based on data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, setcookie, jquery-cookie

I want to set a cookie with the value of the data attribute defined to an anchor link. Example:

- `<a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>`
- `<a href="#" data-lang="fr">Français</a>`

Use case:

- User click change language button
- Language modal pops up showing five different languages. Each link has a different `data-lang`.
- User clicks on what language they want and then a cookie called 'language-selected`is created with the value of the`data-lang` of the chosen lang.

**Setting cookie**: `setCookie('language-selected','data-lang_here',7);`

How would I go about this?

Comment: Please elaborate a little. Are you using pure JS or jQuery as well? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We probably need to see your definition for the setCookie function but from what I can see it expects two strings as an input and data-lang_here IS a string. So maybe you simply need to get rid of the ' ' surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery-cookie plugin. Use `$.cookie('lang-selected')` to get the cookie.

HTML

```
    <a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>
    <a href="#" data-lang="fr">Français</a>
```

Jquery

```
    $("a").click(function($event){
      $event.preventDefault();
      let lang = $($event.target).attr('data-lang');
      $.cookie('language-selected', lang, {expires : 30});
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<a href="#" data-lang="de">Deutsch</a>
<a href="#" data-lang="fr">Français</a>
```

**js**

```
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let anchor of anchors) {
    anchor.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        let langValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-lang');
        setCookie("language-selected", langValue, 1); // expiration time is 1 day
    })
}


function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```